# When to use which derivative expanded function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In our class we have learned the following two formulas for calculating derivative.

$$1.\lim_{x\to a}  \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$$
$$2.\lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

When manually computing derivatives, how do I know which function to use, does it even matter?

Comment: You mean:$$\lim_{x\to a}  \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$$ and $$\lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is used to evaluate the derivative in the point $x = a$. That is:

$$\lim_{x\to a}  \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = f'(a)$$

The second is used to evaluate the derivative for all $x$. That is:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$$

Anyway, the two formulas are equivalent since you can replace in the first one $x-a = h$. Then:

$$x \to a \Rightarrow x -a \to 0 \Rightarrow h \to 0$$
and hence:

$$f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a}  \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{f(h+a) - f(a)}{h} = f'(a)$$

Answer (score 2):

Just set $a = x+h$ and the two formulae are equivalent. Of course, you can't have $ x \rightarrow x+h$ (the variable is in both sides) so you need $h$ to tend to zero.